# Unable to access method of child classes from a List<T> of base class.

Tags: c#

I'm creating a list of class "Task" in a way such as this.

```
List<Task> toDoList = new List<Task>;
```

Task is a base class and have designed it as such:

```
 public class Task : IDetail
{
    string _taskName;            //Task title.
    string _taskDescription;     //Task description.

    public Task(string tn, string td) //Constructor.
    {
        _taskName = tn;
        _taskDescription = td;
    }

    // Method set or return _taskName.
    public string taskName
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskName;
        }

        set
        {
            _taskName = value;
        }
    }

    //Method to set or return _taskDescription.
    public string taskDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskDescription;
        }

        set
        {
            _taskDescription = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual void editList()
    {
        Creator editCreator = new Creator();
        editCreator.Show();
    }


}
```

What i've been trying todo is call methods that exists within the inherited class like one the one i have designate "Note" and have defined it as follows.

```
class Note : Task, IDetail
{
    string _noteDescription;

    public Note(string nd, string tn, string td)    //Constructor.
        : base(tn, td)
    {
        _noteDescription = nd;
    }

    //Method to set or return _noteDescription.
    public string noteDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return _noteDescription;
        }

        set
        {
            _noteDescription = value;
        }
    }

    public override void editList()
    {
        noteBuilder editNote = new noteBuilder();
        editNote.Show();
    }
}
```

However when i try to call a method of the inherited task on the list i get an error. I am trying to access the method as such:

```
toDoList.ElementAt(x).noteDescription;
```

My question is how do i prevent an error from occurring?

the error states

'toDoList.Task' does not contain a definition for 'noteDescription' and no extension method etc etc.

Should i perhaps be  declaring the base class as Abstract? or is there something else i am missing?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: But it's a list of `Task`, not a list of its subclass `Note`.  Why would you expect it to allow you to access properties of `Note`?  What if the list contained instances of `Task` that are *not* instances of `Note`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a `List<Task>`. That could contain *any* kind of `Task` reference - e.g. a *different* derived type, not a `Note`. *Either* you want a `List<Note>` (so it can all be type-safe), or you'll need to cast the element of the list to `Note`:

```
Note note = (Note) toDoList[x];
string description = note.noteDescription;
```

(Given that you've got a `List<T>`, you don't need to use `ElementAt` - use the indexer.)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful :) I didn't know you could deal with a list like it was an Array :)

Answer (score 1):

Filter the list and convert them to notes, like:

```
var noteList = toDoList.Where(x => x is Note)
                       .Select(x => (Note)x)
                       .ToList();
```

then write

```
noteList.ElementAt(x).noteDescription;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Your list is a list of `Task` objects, not `Note` objects.

You'll need to cast your objects to `Note` objects before you can call methods of the `Note` class.

```
(toDoList.ElementAt(x) as Note).noteDescription;
```

or

```
toDoList.Cast<Note>().ElementAt(x).noteDescription;
```

The second option requires all objects in the list be `Note` objects.

Answer (score 0):

notDescription is a property you have for your derived class. But here you are creating a list of your base class

```
List<Task> toDoList = new List<Task>;
```

You can not get the properties of derived class in  a base class. IT works the other way. You can access the properties of base class in your child class.

Answer (score 0):

`toDoList` contains `Task` elements, not `Note` elements.  Now a `Note` element is a type of `Task` element, sure, but polymorphism only works in one direction: you can treat a subclass like its superclass, but you can't treat a superclass like a subclass without casting it first.

If you think about it, you'll realize that it has to be that way.  What if you had a second subclass of `Task` called `Foo`: you can put both of those types in `toDoList`...if you tried to access `noteDescription` on an object that is of type `Foo`, you'd be in trouble.

However, there is a way to do what you want, it just requires a cast:

```
var note = toDoList.ElementAt(x) as Note;
var noteDescription = note==null ? "<not a note>" : note.noteDescription;
```

The other way to do it, of course, would be to move `noteDescription` into `Todo`, where it would be accessible from any subclass of `Todo`, but that's probably not what you want since the name implies that it belongs to `Note`.